Problem with newcomand and luacode environment
The following code allows you to draw regular polygons with tkz-elements and tkz-euclide. To simplify the code, I'd like to use a loop, but unfortunately the tkzelements environment is based on luacode and this leads to a number of restrictions. I can't put the tkzelements environment in a loop, nor within a command. Is there a way around this? Or do I have to transform the tkzelements environment?
The aim is either to be able to perform a loop with the lua code inside, or to perform the lua code in the \drawPolygon command.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[mini]{tkz-euclide} 
\usepackage{tkz-elements}

\begin{document}
\begin{tkzelements}
  z.I      = point:    new (0,0)
  z.A      = point:    new (1,-3)
\end{tkzelements}

\newcommand{\drawPolygon}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
 \def\nb{\tkzUseLua{RP.six.nb}}
 \tkzGetNodes
 \tkzDrawCircles(I,A)
 \tkzDrawPolygon(P_1,P_...,P_\nb)
 \tkzDrawPoints[red](P_1,P_...,P_\nb)
 \end{tikzpicture}
}

\def\n{3}
\begin{tkzelements}
   loadfile ("otherfoo.lua")(\n)
\end{tkzelements}
\drawPolygon
% I'd like to loop the three lines of code above
% even better, by incorporating these three lines into the \drawPolygon command
% Do I need to modify the tkzelements environment to achieve this?

%   \def\n{4}
%  \begin{tkzelements}
%    loadfile ("otherfoo.lua")(\n)
%   \end{tkzelements}
% \drawPolygon
% %etc .

\end{document}

The external file code (otherfoo.lua) :
 local nb = ...
 RP.six   = regular_polygon : new (z.I,z.A,nb)
 RP.six : name ("P_")

The tkzelements environment is defined in tkz-elements.sty.
\newenvironment{tkzelements}
  {   \directlua{scale=1}
      \directlua{tkz_epsilon=1e-8}
      \directlua{tkz_dc=2}
      \directlua{indirect = true}
      \directlua{z={}
                 C={}
                 E={}
                 L={}
                 M={}
                 P={}
                 Q={}
                 R={}
                 RP={}
                 S={}
                 T={}
                 V={}}
      \luacode}
  {\endluacode}



You asked, "[D]o I have to transform the tkzelements environment?" Just out of idle curiosity: Would you know if there's a reason for having 5 separate \direcllua directives in the tkzelements environment? I'm puzzled why there's not a single \directlua directive that performs the required initialization actions. And, why are these initializaton actions performed over and over again, each time the tkzelements environment is entered? Aside: The shift to a luacode environment also seems unnecessary -- at least as long as all that's being run is loadfile ("otherfoo.lua")(\n).

@Mico Good questions : Yes I can indeed use only one directlua directive. I think I need to reset each time. I'm not sure but I had to find a way to empty the tables, then it's necessary to reset the scale to 1 etc... For the other three, this may not be necessary.

@Mico Indeed, one solution is to use only \directlua, but this is less comfortable for the user. They have to do the initialization themselves.

I'm sorry I didn't take David Carlisle's advice about the luacode environment. It seems that using directlua is often preferable.
After modifying the tkz-elements.sty file according to Mico's remarks (I created the lua function init_elements in case of need.) :
  \directlua{
  require "tkz_elements_main"
  tkz_epsilon=1e-8
  tkz_dc=2
  indirect = true
  init_elements()}%

To test the code, I used egreg's answer to this question egreg's answer
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[mini]{tkz-euclide} 
\usepackage{tkz-elements}

\begin{document}
\directlua{
  z.I      = point:    new (0,0)
  z.A      = point:    new (2,0)
}

\def\drawPolygon#1{
\directlua{
  RP.six   = regular_polygon : new (z.I,z.A,#1)
  RP.six : name ("P_")}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
 \def\nb{\tkzUseLua{RP.six.nb}}
 \tkzGetNodes
 \tkzDrawCircles(I,A)
 \tkzDrawPolygon(P_1,P_...,P_\nb)
 \tkzDrawPoints[red](P_1,P_...,P_\nb)
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\foreach [count=\i] \n in {3, 4, ..., 10} {
  \makebox[0.2\textwidth]{%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
      $n=\n$ \\[1ex]
   \drawPolygon{\n}
     \end{tabular}%
  }\ifnum\i=4 \\[2ex]\fi
}

\caption{Regular 3- to 10-gons}

\end{figure}
\end{document}


